# Как поместить изображение в шаблон с помощью PHP?

Tags: php

Пытаюсь разместить произвольную картинку 1920x1080 в стандартной белой 400x300:

```
          //путь к картинке
          $img_initial='/files/source.jpg';
          $img_i = imagecreatefromjpeg($img_initial);// Создаём дескриптор для работы с исходным изображением
          // Создаем шаблон
          $img_o = imagecreatetruecolor($w_o, $h_o);
          // Создаём белый цвет фона
          $white = imagecolorallocate($img_o, 255, 255, 255);
          imagecolortransparent($img_o, $white);
          //пробовал также imagefill($img_o, 0, 0, $white);
          //размеры исходного изображения 1920x1080, поэтому
          $ratio=1080/300;
          $x_i=(1920-1920*$ratio)/2; //сколько отступать от края по горизонтали
         //переносим изображение в шаблон
         imagecopyresampled($img_o, $img_i, 0, 0, $x_i, 0, 400, 300, 1920-2*$x_i, 1080);
         return imagejpeg($img_o, '/files/example.jpg');
```

В итоге получается картинка с черным фоном вокруг. Как исправить?

Comment: imagecolortransparent($new, $white);

Comment: А у меня что написано?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/LtfNbg3m

Comment: вначале тоже был фон чёрный, там фишка в том что наслаивал разные картинки друг с другом

Comment: Так в чем же ошибка у меня?

Comment: нзнаю..........